# Generate new style thumbnail based on existing style using Paperclip and aws-sdk

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, amazon-s3, paperclip

I have a `Photo` model that has 2 styles `:original` and `:medium` where `:medium` is a cropped  version of the original. I would now like to add a `:small` style that's just a resized version of the `:medium`. For new images everything works: I just crop the original image twice, once for the `:medium` and once for the `:small` style. But I also have several thousand existing images that need to be reprocessed to have a `:small` thumb (all stored on AWS S3). Unfortunately, I can't just call `.reprocess! :small` since it will make small versions from the original, while I need small versions based on the cropped `:medium` version.

The medium versions have been cropped by users so I can't just reprocess the originals.

Is there an easy way to do this using Paperclip or do I have to write a script to pull the `:medium` version from S3, resize it locally and then ship it to the `:small` directory on S3?

**UPDATE 1:**

These are my styles

```
:original,  { geometry: "1500x1500>",                       format: :jpg },
:medium,    { geometry: "650x650#", processors: [:cropper], format: :jpg },
:small,     { geometry: "262x262#", processors: [:cropper], format: :jpg }
```

Notice that I've already added the `:small` style, but I still need to generate `:small` thumbs for images that have been created before this addition.

**UPDATE 2:**
The way to do this it is probably using a rake task that would:

1. fetch a `:medium` image from S3 for each photo that was created before `:small` style has been added
2. resize it down to `:small` size
3. upload the resulting image to `/some/path/to/small/image/` on S3

Just not sure where to start.

Comment: This is confusing, is :small just a resized version of :original or do you want it to be based off of :medium?

Comment: @tirdadc sorry, a typo, yes, :small must be a resized version of the :medium. Will fix the question now.

Comment: Can you also post your :styles definitions? Thanks!

Comment: @tirdadc there you go!

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you could use a custom processor. In the past I've copied processors from paperclip and modified them to do what I need. For example if you take the thumbnail processor, modify it so that it crops your thumbnail and resizes it the way you want, and then save it as a custom processor (it should aotu-load if you put it in lib/paperclip).

Either way. Copy the file from https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip/blob/master/lib/paperclip/thumbnail.rb

Edit the section:

```
def transformation_command
  scale, crop = @current_geometry.transformation_to(@target_geometry, crop?)
  trans = []
  trans << "-coalesce" if animated?
  trans << "-auto-orient" if auto_orient
  trans << "-resize" << %["#{scale}"] unless scale.nil? || scale.empty?
  trans << "-crop" << %["#{crop}"] << "+repage" if crop
  trans << '-layers "optimize"' if animated?
 trans
end
```

to crop the image before you resize it. My gess is that you'll have to swap the resize and crop commands, but I'm not sure. All paperclip does is run imagemagick commands so you might find some good documentation here: http://www.imagemagick.org/script/command-line-processing.php

Save this as a custom processor in the lib/paperclip/your_processor_name.rb, and make whatever style you need style like this:

```
:original,  { geometry: "1500x1500>",                       format: :jpg },
:medium,    { geometry: "650x650#", processors: [:your_processor_name], format: :jpg },
:small,     { geometry: "262x262#", processors: [:your_processor_name], format: :jpg }
```

The bottom line is that you can only crop from an original, so if you need custom processing you have to build it. You'll have to play around with it, but this will get you on the right track.

Comment: The thing is I already have a processor in place to crop the `:small` thumb which works well for new uploads.
However, since I've added the `:small` style only recently, there are several thousand images that don't have it, so I need to generate it based of the cropped `:medium` thumb, not the `:original` thumb (which isn't cropped). The solution is probably some sort of a rake task or some custom processor that would re-generate the `:small` thumb based of the `:medium` thumb.

Comment: But the original should still be there, so all you have to do is modify the processor to crop and resize the small images in a rake task like you said. Just find all the images created_at before you started cropping the small and run them through the processor.

Comment: Plus, if you edit the medium images and something goes awry, you can't undo it. Always manipulate the original and save a copy.

Comment: For all the user uploads both `:medium` and `:small` are generated based of the `:original`, but I need to generate `:small` thumb for existing images that don't have it yet (probably using a rake task, not a processor). And since `:small` thumb must be cropped as well, I can only generate them from the existing `:medium` thumbs which are cropped, not from the `:original` that aren't cropped.

Comment: Why can't you use the processor to crop the original to the dimensions of the existing mediums and then resize those to small all within the transformation_command? I've done this before and it has always worked. All you're doing with the processor is reproducing the medium images by plugging the dimensions into the crop command and then resizing. Like I said, you'll have to tinker with the code above, but you'll always have the original to experiment with. If you crop the mediums and something goes wrong, you'll have to figure out how to reproduce them anyway.

Comment: I see what you are saying, but I'm not sure if it's possible to reproduce medium off the original, given that medium was manually cropped by user and we no longer know the coordinates. I think that `:small` thumbs must be generated from `:medium` and then uploaded to their path, I just don't know how to code this.

Comment: Aaaah. I see. I'm editing your question to reflect the fact that the user has cropped the original. Makes a big difference.

Comment: NickM, the user hasn't cropped the original, only medium

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/61443/discussion-between-s-b-and-nickm).